# How to sync files without having Unison installed on the remote server?

Tags: synchronization, unison

Can I push files from a source to a destination using Unison with Unison installed on the source machine but *not* on the destination machine?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it. But no, you won't get the speed benefits that Unison provides when it's running on both ends.

I do this regularly from Mac. I mount a SMB share locally and then set up a `.prf` file like this:

```
# Roots of the synchronization
root = /Volumes/SecondDrive/user/Pix/
root = /Volumes/REMOTE/user/Pix

auto=true
batch=true
times=true
fastcheck=true
```

in the above situation the first `root` is on my local drive and the second is a mounted SMB share that lives on a networked windows server.